# What is the amplitude of the limit cycle of the van der Pol oscillator?

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, non-linear-systems

In the second edition of *Classical dynamics of particles and systems* by Jerry B. Marion, it is said that the van der Pol equation
$$\ddot{x}-\mu\left({x_0}^2-x^2\right)\dot{x}+{\omega_0}^2x=0$$
where $\mu$ is a positive parameter of small value, has a limit cycle with amplitude $|x_0|$ (I'm paraphrasing this from the first edition in spanish) and he even illustrates it as

[image: Marion van der Pol illustration]

In newer editions this has been removed, but they add nothing new whatsoever. From the vdP equation alone it seems that this is right, but I noticed that the limit cycle does not have this amplitude in any $\mu$ case, e.g. for $\mu=0.1$ and $x_0=1$, the plot in phases space looks like (in Mathematica)

[image: van der Pol with $\mu=0.1$, $x_0=1$]

I tried different values and the behaviour is the same, e.g. for $\mu=5$ and $x_0=9$, the plot for position in time is

[image: van der Pol with $\mu=5$, $x_0=9$]

In both cases the amplitude seems to be $2|x_0|$. I think I intuitively understand what's going on by seeing the field lines of the oscillator and how it changes behaviour (damping) when it crosses $x=x_0$, e.g. for $\mu=1$ and $x_0=2$,

[image: van der Pol with $\mu=1$, $x_0=2$]

**But how can I find the *real* amplitude of the limit cycle and why is it not simply $|x_0|$ as the van der Pol equation suggest?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I am not an expert in limit cycles by any means but I am intrigued by this problem so here is what I came up with.

Let's treat the nonlinear term perturbatively. This will not be enough to prove the existence of the limit cycle for large values of $\mu$, but given that apparently there is a proof that this works perturbatively, it will be enough for us.

Let's take an ansatz

\begin{equation}
x(t)=\bar{x}(t)+\mu \delta(t)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}(t)=a\cos(\omega_0 t)
\end{equation}
Here $\mu\delta(t)$ is a small perturbation. Just to be clear, I am thinking of $\mu$ as the small parameter, $\delta$ is not a small function. I am assuming the perturbation will scale like $\mu$ (as opposed to $\mu^2$ or $\mu^3$), this will be justified later. (ok I don't actually explicitly justify it later. The point is that the $O(\mu)$ equation below wouldn't have given any useful information had this scaling been wrong).

By the way, if we could calculate the form of the limit cycle for large $\mu$ we could generalize the analysis by making $\bar{x}$ equal to the limit cycle and then running through all the steps below. The point of the small $\mu$ approximation is that the limit cycle must be approximately the harmonic oscillator path in this limit. I don't know much about this stuff but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to calculate the limit cycle curve.

What we expect to happen is there to be a special value of $a$ such that this ansatz is stable (meaning that $\delta$ will not blow up). Numerically you have discovered that this value is $a=2x_0$, we would like to see if we can see this peturbatively as well.

So we expand out the equation. At $O(\mu^0)$, we find the harmonic oscillator equation, of course.

At $O(\mu)$ we get an equation for $\delta$:

\begin{equation}
\ddot{\delta}+\omega_0^2 \delta = (x_0^2 -\bar{x}^2)\dot{\bar{x}}
\end{equation}

After subbing in the form for $\bar{x}$ and using some trig identities we find

\begin{equation}
\ddot{\delta}+\omega_0^2 \delta = a \omega_0 x_0^2 \sin(3\omega_0 t) + a\omega_0 (a^2-4x_0^2) \cos^2 \omega_0 t \sin \omega_0 t
\end{equation}

This is a forced harmonic oscillator: The right hand side has two forcing terms. Let's look at the second one:
\begin{equation}
\cos^2(\omega_0 t)\sin(\omega_0 t) = \sin(\omega_0 t) - \sin^3(\omega_0 t) = \frac{1}{4}\sin(\omega_0 t) + \frac{1}{4} \sin(3 \omega_0 t)
\end{equation}

There are multiple terms here, but the problem is that there is a term with frequency $\omega_0$. This drives the oscillator at its resonant frequency, creating an instability.

So the fluctuations are unstable so long as that second term is present.

But precisely when $a=2x_0$, the dangerous resonant driving term vanishes, and the fluctuations are stable.

Voila.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! The amplitude for arbitrarily large $\mu$ seems not to change, so maybe there's a way to prove analytically, in general, that it is $\sim2x_0$.